# Bash Git prompt does not hide outside of repository

Tags: git, bash, unix, prompt, ps1

my (simplified) PS1:`export PS1="\A \w\ $(__git_ps1) \$ "`

prompt: `16:08-~/dev (master) $`

This is all good and it shows branch name when there is one. But outside of the repo it still shows `(master)` instead of . I've been searching like crazy but can't find the answer.

What environment information do you need to help me solve this? I'm not that well versed in Bash yet. There has to be something off. Or is there something wrong with my Git version?

```
16:08 ~/dev (master) $ git --version
git version 2.7.4
```

Thanks in advance for taking a look at this!

Answer (score 5):

You are running `__git_ps1` *once*, when you define `PS1`, and using the same value for every prompt later on. You want to run that command *every* time the prompt is displayed, so you need to escape the `$` to prevent command substitution from happening immediately.

```
export PS1='\A \w\ $(__git_ps1) \$ '
```

Comment: You mean to say `export PS1='\A \w\ \$(__git_ps1) \$ '`?
Thanks, that was it. very nice. Edits must be at least 6 characters so if you would be so kind as to add the `\\` to your answer I will accept it as solution.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the use of double quotes in the original version (instead of single quotes). This means `$(__git_ps1)` is evaluated only the first time (when PS1 is .. created?) instead of on every call (as it should).